# Events to run within certain day interval more than once

Tags: mysql

Event structure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `EVENT_NAME` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2013-07-01 09:00:00' ENDS '2013-07-01 09:38:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO update ... Event Query ...
```

this is going to allow the event query to run every five minutes **only** from 9:00 till 9:38

but after it hits 9:38 the event ends and it doesn't work again automatically by it self the next day because its disabled.

any solution i might be missing for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't think that the `SCHEDULE` specification of a MySQL event is as flexible as the `INTERVAL`.

You could roll your own using something like this though:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
EVENT `EVENT_NAME` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
 BEGIN
  IF (hour(now()) = 9 AND minute(now()) <= 38) THEN
   -- Do your stuff here
  END IF;

END$$
```